# Odoo v8 host 127.0.0.1 banned by auth_brute_force

Tags: odoo-8

We were banned by the auth_brute_force since every attempt is coming from 127.0.0.1 (NGINX). Even Admin wasn't able to login.

```
2018-03-28 12:18:29,376 10645 DEBUG ******* openerp.modules.registry: Multiprocess signaling check: [Registry - old# 35 new# 35] [Cache - old# 720 new# 720]
2018-03-28 12:18:29,382 10645 WARNING *******  openerp.addons.auth_brute_force.controllers.controllers: Authentication tried from remote '127.0.0.1'. The request has been ignored because the remote has been banned after 10 attempts without success. Login tried : 'admin'.
2018-03-28 12:18:29,424 10645 INFO ******* werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2018 12:18:29] "POST /web/login HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

We were able to solve this issue by truncating the `res_banned_remote` table in the database. Since there is only one remote address (`localhost`), this will also be the only banned address for now.

```
# su odoo
# psql <database>
psql (x.x.xx)
Type "help" for help.

<database> => truncate res_banned_remote;
TRUNCATE TABLE
<database>=> \q
#
```